# Django Storage S3 bucket Access with IAM Role

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have an EC2 instance attached with an IAM Role.  That role has full s3 access.  The aws cli work perfectly, and so does the meta-data curl check to get the temporary Access and Secret keys.

I have also read that when the Access and Secret keys are missing from the settings module, boto will automatically get the temporary keys from the meta-data url.

I however cannot access the css/js files stored on the bucket via the browser.  When I add a bucket policy allowing a principal of *, everything works.

I tried the following policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyNUM",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "StmtNUM",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/my-role"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
]
```

}

But all css/js are still getting 403's.  What can I change to make it work?

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of trouble by just adding the access and secret keys to your production settings. Do you help setting up a configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Requests from your browser don't have the ability to send the required authz headers, which boto is handling for you elsewhere. The bucket policy cannot determine the principal and is correctly denying the request.

Add another sid to Allow principle * access to everything under /public, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that AWS is setting your files to binary/octet-stream.

check this [solution](http://www.adamwilcox.org/2012/05/04/css-on-amazon-s3/) to handle it.

Comment: I'm getting 403 on all css and js and image files.  This is not a css issue!!

Comment: sorry, was just trying to help.